# What kind of food can I take with me from the United States to Mexico without customs interference?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, mexico

I am considering doing some prospecting in Mexico. I plan to arrive in Morelia, Michoacán, and stay at a hotel called Hotel El Carmen Calle Eduardo Ruiz 63 Centro Historico. I called to find out if they had room service, but they told me they didn't.

I am also totally blind and hard-of-hearing, go I would need plenty of assistance. Fortunately, although I was born here, my family speaks Spanish, so I am fluent in that tongue. In case I'm not satisfied with the Mexican cuisine, what kind of foods or snacks can I take with me from the United States without setting off any flags at the  Mexican customs area?

Answer (score 3):

The site https://www.gob.mx/viajasinplagas has a list of foods that are and are not allowed (in Spanish or English).  Notably, all homemade and handmade foods are forbidden, as well as fresh meats and cheeses.

(Incidentally, while researching this, I also [found](https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/reinounido/index.php/es/servicios-a-extranjeros/79#popup) that it is forbidden to bring [Garbage Pail Kids cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_Pail_Kids) into Mexico!)

Comment: Thanks, but I asked what foods are okay to bring. Based on what you provided, you told me what I can't bring. I would like to plan this trip with as much care as possible.

Comment: @HeavenlyHarmony Did you follow the link?  The _List of agri-food products for tourist import_ PDF contains a list of both allowed and prohibited foods.  The gob.mx website is Mexico government, so can be considered the official source.